# How do I configure WWW::Mechanize to work behind a proxy and https?

Tags: perl

I've written Perl code using WWW::Mechanize to retrieve a webpage. When I retrieve http webpages it works fine but it doesnt work for https. I've checked and I have the Crypt::SSLeay package. What else could be wrong?

The error message is..

```
Error GETing https://www.temp.com: Can't Connect to www.temp.com:443 <Bad hostname 'www.temp.com'> at scrape.pl line 8
```

Comment: Show the error message, add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen in [your related Mechanize question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708648/wwwmechanize-form-not-recognized) that you call the [`proxy` method](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#Proxy_attributes) with only the `http` and `ftp` schemes. Try again with `https` included.

It's probably more useful to set up the [proxy environment variables](http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Proxies/ProxyClients.html) since then all programs can take advantage of this central configuration instead of configuring proxies for each program separately. Do not forget [`https_proxy`](http://p3rl.org/Crypt::SSLeay#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES). Call the [`env_proxy` method](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent#%24ua-%3Eenv_proxy) instead of `proxy` to use them.

Comment: Setting the https_proxy worked for login. But it gives error GETing the dashboard page which is again https://temp.com/dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I needed to add the following in my file

```
$ENV{'HTTPS_PROXY'} = 'http://proxy:port/';
```

for Crypt::SSLeay

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles over this old question: The situation has changed in the recent years.

- starting with version 6 LWP uses IO::Socket::SSL as a backend
- IO::Socket::SSL does not provide its own proxy hacks like Crypt::SSLeay does and LWP https proxy support as documented (e.g. using proxy method or env_proxy) was broken.
- with version 6.06 of both LWP::UserAgent and LWP::Protocol::https (which are now seperate distributions!) https proxy works as expected and documented
- for older versions of LWP one can use Net::SSLGlue::LWP