# WWW::Mechanize and HTTPS proxy

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

How to tell [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) to work with HTTPS proxy?

I have this code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

print "WWW::Mechanize: ", $WWW::Mechanize::VERSION, "\n";
print "LWP : ", $LWP::UserAgent::VERSION, "\n";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->proxy( [ 'http', 'https' ], "https://204.228.129.46:8080/" );

$mech->add_handler("request_send",  sub { shift->dump; return });
$mech->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });

$mech->get("http://people.iu.edu/");
```

And here is my output:

```
WWW::Mechanize: 1.73
LWP : 6.06
GET http://people.iu.edu/
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: WWW-Mechanize/1.73

(no content)
500 Can't connect to 204.228.129.46:8080
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Sat, 31 May 2014 02:26:15 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

Can't connect to 204.228.129.46:8080\n
LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error SSL wants a read first at c:/Perl/site/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 41.\n
Error GETing http://people.iu.edu/: Can't connect to 204.228.129.46:8080
```

**UPDATE**
I have tried `$ENV{...}` tricks with no luck. I mean adding this doesn't help:

```
BEGIN {

    $ENV{'HTTPS_PROXY'} = 'http://204.228.129.46:8080/';
};
```

**UPDATE2** I have read many threads here and on Perlmonks with the same problem (including `connection://` scheme) but with no luck.

**LAST UPDATE** I think **my proxy is broken** because I found that sometimes my code work and sometimes not.

Comment: Googling [`WWW::Mechanize and HTTPS proxy`](https://www.google.com/search?q=WWW%3A%3AMechanize+and+HTTPS+proxy) provided [a lot](http://www.semintelligent.com/blog/articles/15/using-ssl-proxies-with-wwwmechanize-why-doesnt-my-https-proxy-setting-work) of resources for this, including [a previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709414/how-do-i-configure-wwwmechanize-to-work-behind-a-proxy-and-https).

Comment: @Miller I have tried this search without any luck. Previous SO question dated Sep 14 '10 and a lot have changed from these days (I think about LWP::Protocol::https etc). That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @Miller: gangabass is right, the necessary changes were only included recently (version 6.06, releases 04/2014). Before that support for https proxy was broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first attempt should be the correct one, although you probably specified the wrong protocol for the proxy. Based on your attempt with the environment variable and the error message you got, I assume that your http and https proxy itself speaks http, not https (this is usually the case). E.g. he correct way should be:

```
$mech->proxy(['http','https],'http://204.228.129.46:8080/');
```

Alternatively you can set the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables to the same value and use `$mech->env_proxy` to make LWP use them.

But, make sure, that you work with a recent version of LWP and LWP::Protocol::https. Both versions should be at least 6.0.6, because before these versions proxy support for https was broken.  t least in case of LWP this looks good, you might check `$LWP::Protocol::https::VERSION` too. On some Debian/Ubuntu systems it might work also with version 6.05 because they included the necessary patches in 12/2013 already.

If you don't have a recent enough version `Net::SSLGlue::LWP` will monkey-patch your version to have the necessary support.

Comment: Wow! I have old `LWP::Protocol::https` (6.04) but after installing `Net::SSLGlue::LWP` the problem was solved! Thank you for your excellent answer!